# MySql - size VARCHAR

Tags: mysql

Many people say to me that set VARCHAR(100) doesnt make sense. It the same as put 255. I'd like to know why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's rubbish. They may be talking about the fact that a `varchar` uses one byte for the length regardless of whether the maximum length is 100 or 255 ( lengths above that will use two bytes, up to ~64K) but they *are* treated differently.

If you insert a 150-character string into the former, it will be truncated to 100, that's not so for the latter case.

You should use the length that makes sense. If you have a column that will never exceed 30 characters, *don't* use `varchar(255)`.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) for the type details.

Comment: Uhm ok, is my case that I have string that never exceed of 30 characters. But if I put varchar(30) or varchar(255) i use the same memory space right? So it's indifferent...

Comment: Yes, right up until the point where some rogue application inserts _more_ than 30 characters :-)

Comment: Uhm ok...but I prefeer check the variables server side. After I'll put them on a varchar(255). So, if i see variables with more chars on the website, then I'll know that the PHP script has failed :)

Comment: @markzzz, it's a division-of-responsibility issue. The DBMS (at least in important enterprise environments) should be fully responsible for it's own data consistency. That includes column properties such as lengths. Otherwise anyone with a password that can connect to your database can bypass checks that your application makes, just by coding up a JDBC application.

Comment: Of course. Anyway, if a user get my password, bypass the checks will be the last of my problems :)

Comment: That's strange anyway! If you check the table on your link, you can see : 'ab' = 3bytes; 'abcd'= 5bytes about the varchar(4). Why?

Comment: @markzz, what they're getting at there is that you have to store a _length_ (one byte or two depending on the max column size) as well as the data itself. Hence `ab` needs `{2,'a','b'}`.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242%28v=sql.80%29.aspx.

VARCHAR(100) does makes sense, it says that the max size of the input is 100 chars(if you will insert a longer string it will cut it to a size 100).

VARCHAR(256) it says that the max size of the input is 256 chars.